# Control of text position using the decorations.text library in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a two properties that I have been struggling to implement in the `decorations.text` library for the following image. My two questions are:

[image]

1) How do I control the text position along the line? Normally I would use something like the following - I can control the position of the text using `pos=0.2` but it doesn't appear to work in the `decorations.text` library.

```
\draw [dashed] (\mylt,\mytop) .. controls (\mylt+4cm,\mytop-2cm) and (\mylt+8cm,\mytop-2cm) .. (\mylt+15cm,\mytop-2cm) node [pos=0.2, above, sloped] (TextNode) {Overall influence curve};
```

2) Can I offset the text from the line slightly? It looks a bit squashed.

Minimal working example below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newlength{\mylt}
\newlength{\mytop}
\setlength{\mylt}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\mytop}{-1cm}
\draw [dashed, postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={Overall influence curve}}}] (\mylt,\mytop) .. controls (\mylt+4cm,\mytop-2cm) and (\mylt+8cm,\mytop-2cm) .. (\mylt+15cm,\mytop-2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

David

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can control position along the line with `align` option. You can define some `left indent` or `right indent` values to indicate where to start or end the text.

I don't know how to set a vertical offset but may be you can `\draw` a vertically shifted  line and later `\path` the decorated text over the same non shifted line.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newlength{\mylt}
\newlength{\mytop}
\setlength{\mylt}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\mytop}{-1cm}
\draw [dashed, postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={Overall influence curve}}}] (\mylt,\mytop) .. controls (\mylt+4cm,\mytop-2cm) and (\mylt+8cm,\mytop-2cm) .. (\mylt+15cm,\mytop-2cm);

\begin{scope}[yshift=1cm]
\draw [dashed, postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align={left, left indent=1cm}, text={Overall influence curve}}}] (\mylt,\mytop) .. controls (\mylt+4cm,\mytop-2cm) and (\mylt+8cm,\mytop-2cm) .. (\mylt+15cm,\mytop-2cm);
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[yshift=2cm]
\draw[yshift=-3mm] (\mylt,\mytop) .. controls (\mylt+4cm,\mytop-2cm) and (\mylt+8cm,\mytop-2cm) .. (\mylt+15cm,\mytop-2cm);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align={right,right indent=4cm}, text={Overall influence curve}}}] (\mylt,\mytop) .. controls (\mylt+4cm,\mytop-2cm) and (\mylt+8cm,\mytop-2cm) .. (\mylt+15cm,\mytop-2cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: Vertical shift**

As jlovegren suggested, `raise` option inside`decoration` could be used to introduce the desired separation between path and text. Previous code with different `raise` options and simplified third `scope` looks like:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newlength{\mylt}
\newlength{\mytop}
\setlength{\mylt}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\mytop}{-1cm}
\draw [dashed, postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={Overall influence curve},raise=1mm}}] (\mylt,\mytop) .. controls (\mylt+4cm,\mytop-2cm) and (\mylt+8cm,\mytop-2cm) .. (\mylt+15cm,\mytop-2cm);

\begin{scope}[yshift=1cm]
\draw [dashed, postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align={left, left indent=1cm}, text={Overall influence curve}, raise=-5mm}}] (\mylt,\mytop) .. controls (\mylt+4cm,\mytop-2cm) and (\mylt+8cm,\mytop-2cm) .. (\mylt+15cm,\mytop-2cm);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=2cm]
\draw [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align={right,right indent=4cm}, text={Overall influence curve}, raise=3mm}}] (\mylt,\mytop) .. controls (\mylt+4cm,\mytop-2cm) and (\mylt+8cm,\mytop-2cm) .. (\mylt+15cm,\mytop-2cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ignasi, thank you that was exactly what I was looking for! I like the use of the `scope` command as well; haven't seen that before.

Comment: For the vertical offset, you can do something like `decoration={...,raise=2pt,...}`.

Comment: @jlovegren Thank you. I've updated the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You could instead use `text effects along path` which allows you to apply effects on a character-by-character basis, such as shifting the text above or below the line of the curve or to the left or right. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newlength{\mylt}
    \newlength{\mytop}
    \setlength{\mylt}{1.5cm}
    \setlength{\mytop}{-1cm}
    \draw
      [dashed,
      postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
          text effects along path,
          text align=center,
          text={Overall influence curve},
          text effects/.cd,
          characters={text along path, yshift=5pt}
        }
      }
      ] (\mylt,\mytop) .. controls (\mylt+4cm,\mytop-2cm) and (\mylt+8cm,\mytop-2cm) .. (\mylt+15cm,\mytop-2cm);
    \scoped[yshift=-10mm]{
      \draw
        [dashed,
        postaction={
          decorate,
          decoration={
            text effects along path,
            text align=left,
            text={Overall influence curve},
            text effects/.cd,
            characters={text along path, yshift=10pt, xshift=20mm}
          }
        }
        ] (\mylt,\mytop) .. controls (\mylt+4cm,\mytop-2cm) and (\mylt+8cm,\mytop-2cm) .. (\mylt+15cm,\mytop-2cm);}
    \scoped[yshift=-20mm]{
      \draw
        [dashed,
        postaction={
          decorate,
          decoration={
            text effects along path,
            text align=right,
            text={Overall influence curve},
            text effects/.cd,
            characters={text along path, yshift=-15pt, xshift=-20mm}
          }
        }
        ] (\mylt,\mytop) .. controls (\mylt+4cm,\mytop-2cm) and (\mylt+8cm,\mytop-2cm) .. (\mylt+15cm,\mytop-2cm);}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: curves with shifted text]

Comment: Is there a way to (1) allow for the decorated text to have citations? (I get an error message when I try to add a \cite{} command (2) modify the size? (Adding \scriptsize in front doesn't seem to help)