# How can I improve the text wrap in these tikz arrows?

Tags: positioning

Consider the following diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows, positioning}
\tikzset{->,>=stealth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (A) at (1, 0) {$A$};
        \node (P) at (4, -4) {$P$};
        \node (C) at (9, -2) {$C$};
        \node (Z) at (9, 2) {$Z$};
        \node (D) at (4, 4) {$D$};
        \node (D') at (-2, 4) {$D'$};
        \node (PL) at (-2, -4) {$PL$};
        \node (L) at (-7, -2) {$L$};
        \node (L') at (-7,2 ) {$L'$};
        \draw (A) to (P);
        \draw[densely dotted] (L) to node[above,rotate= 13,black]{\scriptsize Some text here}(A);
        \draw (P) to node[below,rotate= 21,black]{\scriptsize Longer comment.}(C);
        \draw (C) to node[above,rotate= -90,black]{\scriptsize Short comment.}(Z);
        \draw[bend left =15, densely dotted] (PL) to node[ above right=of D,rotate=45,black]{\scriptsize A useful remark here.}(D);
        \draw (D) to (Z);
        \draw (A) to (D);
            \draw[densely dotted] (A) to node[above,rotate= -13,black]{\scriptsize Some more text.}
(C);
        \draw[bend right =15, densely dotted] (D') to node[below right=of A,rotate=-45,black]{\scriptsize More text here, too}(P);
        \draw (PL) to node[below,rotate=52,black]{\scriptsize Text here,too.}(A);
        \draw (L) to node[below,rotate= -21,black]{\scriptsize Some more text.} (PL);
        \draw (D') to (A);
        \draw (L') to (D');
        \draw (L') to node[above,rotate= 90,black]{\scriptsize The last bit of text}(L);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which renders as

[image]

I am perfectly happy with the non-curved arrows, but it would be nice if the text curved with the arrows, and could be put in the last third of the arrow. What's the way to do this?

Comment: (Note: the non-curved has a nice space with respect to the arrows, but thee curved doesn't!)

Comment: I have this error: `Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function of (in 'of D'). [...ack]{\scriptsize A useful remark here.}(D)]`.

Comment: @Sebastiano `tikz` library `positioning` is required. I've edit the question to make the code snippet a complete example.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you very much. I suggest to use `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}` with the option `text along path,text align=center` and the option `raise=<..>ex`, with a number into `<...>` to give more blank space.

Comment: @Sebastiano Could you provide an answer with a MWE? I can't seem to make this work.

Comment: Actually I think [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231076/control-of-text-position-using-the-decorations-text-library-in-tikz) answers my question...

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I hope to make it :-) but I'm not sure..+1 for you..Don't worry we will help you. :-) Best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano OK. I didn't mention this but I do need the text to be small (\scriptsize) and I need it to have \cite{} environments. I am having trouble achieving either of these two things...

Comment: @Sebastiano Looks like one just needs to use |\scriptsize|, though this doesn't work for citations...

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Can you help you with this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458554/tikz-graph-with-citations to have `\cite{}`environments? I have never done this operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I commented the lines of your code without deleting them and just underneath, I put the new code.
If you need an explanation, just say so, I'll explain more fully.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{->,>=stealth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (A) at (1, 0) {$A$};
        \node (P) at (4, -4) {$P$};
        \node (C) at (9, -2) {$C$};
        \node (Z) at (9, 2) {$Z$};
        \node (D) at (4, 4) {$D$};
        \node (D') at (-2, 4) {$D'$};
        \node (PL) at (-2, -4) {$PL$};
        \node (L) at (-7, -2) {$L$};
        \node (L') at (-7,2 ) {$L'$};
        \draw (A) to (P);
        \draw[densely dotted] (L) to node[above,rotate= 13,black]{\scriptsize Some text here}(A);
        \draw (P) to node[below,rotate= 21,black]{\scriptsize Longer comment.}(C);
        \draw (C) to node[above,rotate= -90,black]{\scriptsize Short comment.}(Z);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% ---- old path ------------------------------------------------------
%        \draw[bend left =15, densely dotted] (PL) to node[ above right=of D,rotate=45,black]{\scriptsize A useful remark here.}(D);
% ---- new path decorated with the text «A useful remark here» --------
        \draw [bend left =15, densely dotted,-latex, postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=3pt,text along path,text align={right,right indent=8mm},text={|\scriptsize|A useful remark here}}}] (PL) to  (D);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \draw (D) to (Z);
        \draw (A) to (D);
            \draw[densely dotted] (A) to node[above,rotate= -13,black]{\scriptsize Some more text.}
(C);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% ---- old path -------------------------------------------------------
%        \draw[blue,bend right =15, densely dotted] (D') to node[below right=of A,rotate=-45,black]{\scriptsize More text here, too}(P);
% ---- new path decorated with the text «More text here, too» ----------
        \draw [bend right =15, densely dotted,-latex, postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=3pt,text along path,text align={right,right indent=10mm},text={|\scriptsize|More text here, too}}}] (D') to  (P);  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      
        \draw (PL) to node[below,rotate=52,black]{\scriptsize Text here,too.}(A);

        \draw (L) to node[below,rotate= -21,black]{\scriptsize Some more text.} (PL);
        \draw (D') to (A);
        \draw (L') to (D');
        \draw (L') to node[above,rotate= 90,black]{\scriptsize The last bit of text}(L);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is only a partial answer with the text curved with the arrows because I'm not able to put the `\cite{}` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{->,>=stealth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (A) at (1, 0) {$A$};
        \node (P) at (4, -4) {$P$};
        \node (C) at (9, -2) {$C$};
        \node (Z) at (9, 2) {$Z$};
        \node (D) at (4, 4) {$D$};
        \node (D') at (-2, 4) {$D'$};
        \node (PL) at (-2, -4) {$PL$};
        \node (L) at (-7, -2) {$L$};
        \node (L') at (-7,2 ) {$L'$};
        \draw (A) to (P);
        \draw[densely dotted] (L) to node[above,rotate= 13,black]{\scriptsize Some text here}(A);
        \draw (P) to node[below,rotate= 21,black]{\scriptsize Longer comment.}(C);
        \draw (C) to node[above,rotate= -90,black]{\scriptsize Short comment.}(Z);
        \draw [densely dotted,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=1ex,text along path,text align=center,text={|\scriptsize|A useful remark here.}}}] (PL) to [bend left=45] (D);
        \draw (D) to (Z);
        \draw (A) to (D);
            \draw[densely dotted] (A) to node[above,rotate= -13,black]{\scriptsize Some more text.}
(C);
\draw [densely dotted,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=1ex,text along path,text align=center,text={|\scriptsize|More text here, too.}}}] (D') to [bend left=345] (P);
        \draw (PL) to node[below,rotate=52,black]{\scriptsize Text here,too.}(A);
        \draw (L) to node[below,rotate= -21,black]{\scriptsize Some more text.} (PL);
        \draw (D') to (A);
        \draw (L') to (D');
        \draw (L') to node[above,rotate= 90,black]{\scriptsize The last bit of text}(L);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]